# Mark a Jasmine test as skipped while using the Karma-Jasmine provider in Karma-Runner?

Tags: jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I have this jasmine test that I'm running with Karma:

```
describe('When a logged in user chooses Rent and Payment PIN is enabled', function() {
    beforeEach(function(){

    });

    afterEach(function() {

    });

    it('should be presented with a dialog to enter the pin', function() {
       //test to be skipped
    })
})
```

And I want to see on report that this test has been skipped and come back to test when all stuff needed for test will be ready.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: I have the same problem. It's easy to skip a test (just change 'it' to 'xit'), but I haven't found a way to have the fact that a test was skipped reflected in the report when I run karma.

Comment: I have found an [issue on github](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-jasmine/issues/3) about it. If you're still interested, leave comment there to attract the focus of developers

Answer (score 8):

You might try using the [`pending`](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html#section-Pending_Specs) function in your spec.  According to the doc, pending specs don't run, but names still show up in the results.  For 2.0, it also says an empty method body should work.  Try:

```
it('should be presented with a dialog to enter the pin', function() {
   pending();
})
```

or

```
it('should be presented with a dialog to enter the pin');
```